# Java Access Bridge Textbox element inaccessiblity in tree c#

Tags: java, c#, oracle, java-access-bridge

I am automating java applications with **Java access bridge in C#**. I have been successful in accessing a complete Tree of the target java application, and am able to retrieve values out of all kinds of elements like Buttons, Checkboxes, Radiobuttons, and even Textboxes.
I have implemented [Access Bridge Explorer](https://github.com/google/access-bridge-explorer) code to have everything done.

However, **only some of the Textboxes** in the same target java application go **inaccessible** in the tree hierarchy, thereby making it *fully invisible to my c# application as well as to the Access bridge explorer app*.

Upon inspecting in **Java Ferret** and comparing with other textboxes that are "accessible" & whose values are retrievable, I found that these **weird textboxes have an index of -1** in their parent node. Thier parent property would have values "unknown" OR "No parent", whereas, the normal accessbile textboxes have a proper index in parent, and actual parent references.

Could somebody help me out to get these textboxes to be accessible in the tree along with access to their text values?
Appreciate any kind of clues. Much regards.

**Note:** Only Java Ferret is able to access such textboxes on hover of themouse. Java Monkey also fails to recognize these textbox elements in the tree. Also attached below is a screenshot of Java Ferret spying a sample Java application - [image]